# Ubuntu 16.04 erases /etc/resolv.conf after restart

Tags: networking, dns

I'm new user on Ubuntu and I need your help.

I would like to configure DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`, so I used this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

I changed my DNS server and it was OK but, after restarting,  my changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` were removed and the default configuration was restored.

I have tried the command below but it failed:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
chattr: Opération non supportée lors de la lecture des drapeaux sur /etc/resolv.conf
```

in english: 
chattr : Operation not supported when reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf

What can I do?

Comment: FWIW you probably get the `chattr: Opération non supportée` error because the thing you are trying to change the attributes of is actually a *symbolic link* (to run/resolvconf/resolv.conf) - to use `chattr -i` here, you'd need to remove the link and create a regular file first. However there are **much** better ways to achieve what you want **without** brute force, as described in the answers below.

Comment: Hello Arronical and thank. I need find the best solution. Can you know if it's possible change this symbolic link for change everytime /etc/resolv.conf?

Answer (score 5):

Hello Saturne64 and welcome to Askubuntu! The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are ultimately overwritten, but we can still set your DNS server of choice for your computer through the Network Manager. Please follow these steps:

1. Click the wifi icon at the top-right of your screen and choose "Network Connections"
2. Click "Edit"
3. Click the "IPV4 Settings" tab
4. Next to "Method: ", click "Automatic (DHCP)" and choose "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"
5. In the text box adjacent to "DNS Servers: ", type the address of your preferred DNS server.
6. Click "Save" and in a terminal, run `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`.

Let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: hello user and thank's. I have follow your answer and after that i use nslookup www.free.fr Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
my configuration don't working with my dns. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Potentially, yes; allow me to explain. On my computer, I use dnscrypt as a dns forwarder, and it is bound to port 127.0.2.1 port 53. But Network Manager doesn't allow me to save my dns settings if, for example, I enter "127.0.2.1:53" in the DNS Servers box. Only when I leave off the ":53", I am allowed to save my settings, and they work after issuing the restart command above. I assume this is because Network Manager assumes port 53. Did you enter a port number in the box for your setup, and if so, could you remove it, save your settings, and then restart Network Manager?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the DNS settings in whatever tool you use to configure your network (for example NetworkManager or `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Alternatively, you can uninstall `resolvconf` to revert to a more traditional setup (or old-fashioned, depending on your point of view).